# Execute function with given parameters

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if someone could help me refine this piece of code, in my eyes it is not a nice function to execute are there ways to reduce this function in lines?

This is my function:

```
function changeStyling(input, changeSelector, elementCssChange, pixels) {
   if(!reload){
    if(changeSelector === '.exit-intent-wrapper' && elementCssChange === 'background') {
        this.base64PopupBGImg = null, document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[elementCssChange] = `${input.value}`;
    }

    pixels ? 
        document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[elementCssChange] = `${input.value}px` : 
        document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[elementCssChange] = `${input.value}`;
  } else {
    pixels[i] ? document.querySelector(changeSelector[i]).style[elementCssChange[i]] = `${input[i].value}px` : document.querySelector(changeSelector[i]).style[elementCssChange[i]] = input[i].value;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    }
}
```

}

And this is how i execute it on reload:

```
changeStyling(
        [
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"), 
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentHeight"), 
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentRadius"),
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentPaddingAll"),
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentPadding"),
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentPaddingLeft"),
            document.querySelector(".exitIntentPaddingRight"),

            document.querySelector(".btnWidth"),
            document.querySelector(".btnHeight"),
            document.querySelector(".btnRadius"),
            document.querySelector(".btnColor"),
            document.querySelector(".btnTextColor")
        ], 
        [
            '.exit-intent-wrapper',
            '.exit-intent-wrapper',
            '.exit-intent-wrapper',
            '.exit-intent-wrapper',
            '.exit-intent-inner',
            '.exit-intent-inner',
            '.exit-intent-inner',

            '.button',
            '.button',
            '.button',
            '.button',
            '.button'
        ],
        [
            'width',
            'height',
            'borderRadius',
            'padding',
            'padding',
            'paddingLeft',
            'paddingRight',

            'width',
            'height',
            'borderRadius',
            'backgroundColor',
            'color'
        ],
        [ true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false ]
    );
```

Does someone know how I can reduce the execute of the function?

Comment: If it's working code it likely belongs on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: Don't use `?:` in void context. `foo ? x = bar : x = baz;` is better written as `x = foo ? bar : baz;`.

Comment: you'd have to at least tell us the exact requirements, otherwise we don't know which bits are potentially redundant

Comment: But seriously, you're way overusing `?:`. Half of those should be `if`.

Comment: An array of objects is better than a bunch of parallel arrays (i.e. use `objects[i].foo` and `objects[i].bar` instead of `foo[i]` and `bar[i]`).

Comment: @melpomene could you show it in my case?

Comment: What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: An array of objects which are better than a bunch of parallel arrays

Comment: I agree this probably belongs in codereview.stackexchange.com.  That aside, I'm noticing `document.querySelector(changeSelector)` and `${input.value}` a lot in the code, which could be stored to a variable.  And since you are doing a few similar transformations multiple times, that might be a good candidate for functionality encapsulated in a function.

Comment: Also I very much agree with melpmene's other points regarding collapsing the arrays to objects and replacing confusing ternary use with `if`/`else` blocks.  It may result in more lines, but readability is as important as succinctness.

Comment: `changeStyling([ { input: document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"), changeSelector: '.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty: 'width', pixels: true }, { ... }, ... ]);` Then you can have `function changeStyling(objects) { ... objects[i].input ... objects[i].changeSelector ... etc }`. It keeps related values together in the function call.

Comment: Hi, for more readability you could setup an object which holds `input, changeSelector, elementCssChange` and `pixels` as attributes. Then you put these in you function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently uses parallel arrays, which are very confusing and difficult to modify. I recommend either multidimensional arrays or objects.

```
function changeStyling(input) {
   if(!reload){
    if(input.changeSelector === '.exit-intent-wrapper' && input.elementCssChange === 'background') {
        this.base64PopupBGImg = null, document.querySelector(input.changeSelector).style[input.elementCssChange] = `${input.el.value}`;
    }

    pixels ? 
        document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[input.elementCssChange] = `${input.el.value}px` : 
        document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[input.elementCssChange] = `${input.el.value}`;
  } else {
    pixels[i] ? document.querySelector(input.changeSelector[i]).style[input.elementCssChange[i]] = `${input.el[i].value}px` : document.querySelector(input.changeSelector[i]).style[input.elementCssChange[i]] = input.el[i].value;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    }
}


changeStyling(
        [
            {
                el:document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"),
                changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper',
                elementCssChange:'width'
                //Continue for any necessary modifications
            },
            {
                el:document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"),
                changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper',
                elementCssChange:'width'
                //Continue for any necessary modifications
            },
        ]);
```

Please note, I haven't tested this code, it might not work like expected